# Is it possible to send an audio file as request parameter

Tags: java, javascript, url

I have the following URL

`http:actionname.php?user=username&password=pwd&sender=no&audio_file=somefilehere`

I want to send an audio file along with the above parameters.

Is it possible to send an audio file as a request parameter?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the name of a file, but not the file itself. URL lengths are limited, practically to about 2000 characters. Theoretically they may be a bit longer, but this is not supported on all browsers. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/79485).

If the file is publicly available, and the file name is a URL itself, the server may fetch the file later.

If you want to send a file, consider having a POST request with the file content in it.

Comment: That means which is available in the internet only i can send.Am i right

Comment: @PSR You can send the URL, then the server gets the file using the URL in the request. For example like this: http://quir.li/player.html?media=http%3A%2F%2Fquir.li%2Fmedia%2Flidija_roos-sweet_taste.mp3&title=Sweet%20taste&artist=Lidija%20Roos&album=Not%20for%20sale&0=Intro&15=Verse%201&45.5=Verse%202&75.94=Chorus&106.75=Verse%203&140.75=Chorus&172.07=Bridge&201.65=Chorus&232.65=Outro

Answer (score 0):

As usually, you will send anything as request to web server, the file content will be transferred as internals of HTTP message (POST parameters as file name, and content separately) outgoing from you to the server, until it finished (it is TCP session and it won't be break up while data is streaming), it could be considered as "request" to web server.

Theoretically, you could send something via URL (HTTP GET request), but you could develop some kind of transport data-over-HTTP-GET protocol to send escaped binary data chunks as GET parameters. It is possible :)

Even sending (uploading) file via POST request also no so plain as submitting form with usual POST parameters, you should use `multipart/form-data` encoding in the form and special treatment on the server side for that.

It is not good, but not so weird as transmitting data via URL, you could send some data within GET request to the server, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body?lq=1) for more.